# Transit visa means?

Tags: switzerland, poland

Dear all I have a transit visa issue from Geneva for two days I am travelling to non Europe from Warsaw but I have a domestic flight from Geneva to Warsaw so I am allowed to enter Poland for visit because my next flight is in next 20 Hours.

Comment: How does your visa indicate that it is a transit visa?

Comment: Where are you now? What visa do you have?

Comment: What is the question? It's not clear.

Answer (score 2):

A flight from Geneva to Warsaw is treated as a domestic flight. Therefore it will be acccessed from the "land side" of immigration control.

So if you can take that flight you can also leave the airports.

If you have a type C visa then you are fine.

If you have a type A visa then you can't fly your proposed itinary at all.

(AIUI type B no longer exists)